# Code not executed in sequence

Tags: javascript, sql, pouchdb, cloudant, nosql

I have a document in my cloudant db with `_id` of `mittens13`. I tried to query it and alert, one in the query statement and another one outside the query statement.

However, the one outside the query statement were called first and it gave an alert of `undefined` and then it gave another alert `hello` which was the item in the doc. May I know why?

Javascript code

```
function queryDB() {

    var price;

    db.get("mittens13", function (err, response) {
        console.log(err || response);
        alert(response.title);
        price = response.title;
    });

    alert(price);
}
```

Details of the doc in my db

```
{
  "_id": "mittens13",
  "_rev": "1-78ef016a3534df0764bbf7178c35ea11",
  "title": "hello",
  "occupation": "kitten123"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2):

Question: Why is `alert(price);` producing `undefined`?

The reason why your `alert(price)`shows undefined, even though the code is written after your `db.get` code, is because `db.get` is asynchronous.

Because it is an asynchronous call, your program will not wait for the response of `db.get` before it continues. So before your `db.get` comes back, your program has already reached the `alert(price);` line. It looks and sees that the only other code that has been written regarding price is `var price;`. Which, if you tried to print, would result in undefined.

You should research ajax and callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

db.get is asyncronous, so when alert(price) is called the function before it is actually still running (on a different thread).  I think the correct way would be:

```
db.get("mittens13", function (err, response) {
    console.log(err || response);
    alert(response.title);
    price = response.title;
}).then(function(){ alert(price) };
```

the .then allows the alert(price) to run only after the previous task as finished, it also runs on the same thread (i believe, somebody will probably correct me).  also a small side note, you should probably add some error checking and if you catach an error be sure to cancel the task continuation (.then)